# Windows command line %argument was unexpected at this time (with single percentage!)

Tags: batch-file, windows-console

I'm trying to run the following command in a **command prompt**, with single percentage for the argument, as it should be for command prompt instructions:

```
for /F %remote in ('git branch -a') do (git branch --track %remote) && git fetch --all && git pull --all
```

But I still get the following error:

> %remote was unexpected at this time.

There's a lot of issues with this "argument was unexpected at this time". I've searched and searched but almost all solutions refer to the same confusion between using % or %%. Double percentages should only be used in batch files. But I'm using the proper notation. Why doesn't it work?

Could it be because of the parenthesis? I don't know if [this issue mentioned on Microsoft's website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2524009/error-running-command-shell-scripts-that-include-parentheses) is relevant or not.

Comment: Third line of the help file: `%variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Read the Documentation**

```
C:\>for /?
Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.

FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
```

Notice how the ***3rd line*** of the documentation says *"single letter"*

*(the complete help text is 153 lines long. I recommend reading it ALL)*

Comment: Your avatar probably represented you pretty clearly as you were typing that eh? :). Thank you.

Comment: @Axonn, an astute observation!  To bad the eye roll wasn't an animated. LOL.

Comment: I'm confused, is the third line what is missing from the command?

Comment: @cloudiebro:  The OP tried to use loop variable `%remote`.  The documentation clearly says loop variables must be ***a single letter***.  `%r` is OK, but `%remote` is more than a single letter and not OK.  Their command should be: `for %r in (...) do (...)`